# Matlab R2015b vs R2015a - table in parfor loop - transparancy violation

Tags: matlab, version, transparency, parfor

I am currently experiencing a basic transparency violation error when creating a table in a parfor loop. The most confusing point it that the exact same example code works in R2015a, but does not work anymore in the newer version R2015b.

To simulate the problem i am running the following code on both Matlab versions:

```
A = [1,2,3,4];

parfor i=1:5
  table(A)
end
```

Doing so returns the following error:

> Error using table (line 247) Transparency violation error.
>   See
>   Parallel Computing Toolbox documentation about Transparency

I am now curious to hear if anyone experienced the same issue or if anyone can provide an explanation for this. Using the prior version both my initial code and also this simple example worked like a charm.

Comment: Calling `table` without explicitly defining the output variable causes the `parfor` loop to try and create `ans` without you telling it to. Variable creation that is not explicitly stated is prohibited for transparent workspaces. It's strange to me that the provided sample code works in any MATLAB version.

Comment: Now fixed in R2019b.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is because the workspace transparency checks in R2015b got more stringent, and disallow the use of `inputname`, which is what the `table` constructor is using. I think the only way to fix this is to move the `table` construction function call into a function called from within your `parfor` loop. I.e.

```
parfor idx = 1:1
  t{idx} = iBuildTable(idx);
end

function t = iBuildTable(varargin)
  t = table(varargin{:});
end
```

NOTE: The original problem has been fixed in R2019b of MATLAB, out now (released 2019-09-11).